I have an Angular SSG app that fetches data from a 3rd party API during initialization that doesn't work when navigating
I have an Angular V17 standalone app that fetches blog posts from a 3rd party API during initialization. The server side rendering work fines and the HTML that gets sent over contains the information with the blog posts.
If I navigate away from the component (still in the app) and then return to the original component, the data is no longer there. It seems like my data service is not holding on to its properties for some reason.
Any help would be much appreciated.
app.routes.ts
export const appRoutes: Route[] = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  {
    path: 'articles',
    component: PostListComponent,
    children: [],
  },
];

export function childRoutesFactory(posts: PostsService) {
  return () =>
    posts.loadPosts().pipe(
      tap((posts) => {
        const childRoutes: Route[] = [];
        posts.forEach((post) => {
          if (post?.slug) {
            childRoutes.push({
              path: post.slug,
              component: PostDetailsComponent,
              data: { post: post },
            });
          }
        });

        appRoutes.forEach((route) => {
          if (route.path === 'articles') {
            route.children = childRoutes;
          }
        });
        return appRoutes;
      }),
    );
}

app.config.ts
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: childRoutesFactory,
      deps: [PostsService],
      multi: true,
    },
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideRouter(
      appRoutes,
      withInMemoryScrolling(
        // { scrollPositionRestoration: 'top' }
      ),
      withComponentInputBinding(),
      withEnabledBlockingInitialNavigation(),
    ),
    provideHttpClient(withFetch()),
  ],
};

posts.service.ts
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PostsService {
  http = inject(HttpClient);
  posts: Post[] = [];

  loadPosts() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    });
    return this.http
      .get<
        Post[]
      >('postsURL', { headers: headers })
      .pipe(
        map((val) => val.filter((el) => el.title !== 'Coming soon')),
        tap((posts) => this.posts = posts),
      );
  }

posts-display.component.ts
The PostDisplayComponent is used inside the HomeComponent.
When trying to access the postsService.posts property directly from my service, I get an empty array. When I try to call the API again to populate it (like I do below), I get a CORS error.
export class PostsDisplayComponent {
  postsService = inject(PostsService);

  posts = toSignal(this.postsService.loadPosts(), { initialValue: [] });
  featuredPost = computed(() =>
    this.posts().find((val) => val.id === ID),
  );

